# Replace if-without-else in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

How do you usually use to replace if-without-else in Scala in functional way?

For example, like this typical pattern in imperative style:

```
var list = List("a", "b", "c")

if (flag) { // flag is boolean variable
    // do something inside if flag is true
    list = "x" :: list
}
// if flag is false, nothing happened
```

I'm thinking like this to make it functional:

```
val tempList = List("a", "b", "c")
val list = if (flag) "x" :: tempList else tempList
```

Could there be a better way without using intermediary variable?

So anyone can share how do you eliminate if-without-else in scala?

Comment: In functional programming, there usually is no `if` without an `else` - you always need to get *some* value back. You only might not need to declare it explicitly, when you use a function that provides a default value.

Comment: Your second version looks fine to me. Clear what's going on, no mutable vars, no problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's generally better to avoid cluttering your namespace with temporary variables.  So something like this would be better:

```
val list = {
  val temp = List("a", "b", "c")
  if (flag) "x" :: temp else temp
}
```

or

```
val list = List("a", "b", "c") match {
  case x if flag => "x" :: x
  case x => x
}
```

If you find yourself doing this a *lot* and performance is not a big concern, it might be handy to define an extension method.  I have one in my personal library that looks like this:

```
implicit class AnythingCanPickFn[A](private val underlying: A) extends AnyVal {
  /** Transforms self according to `f` for those values where `p` is true. */
  @inline def pickFn(p: A => Boolean)(f: A => A) =
    if (p(underlying)) f(underlying) else underlying
}
```

You'd use this one like so:

```
List("a", "b", "c").pickFn(_ => flag){ "x" :: _ }
```

Comment: I totally agree with the less local "variables" principle. For even less cluttering, you can replace the `x` in the first match with a `_`

Comment: Shouldn't that be `"x" :: x` in that `match` case?

Comment: @Bergi - Yes it should.  Fixed, thanks!  (I should know better than to try to rename variables after testing.)

Answer (score 2):

You could skin the cat by making the optional part optional:

```
scala> val flag = true
flag: Boolean = true

scala> Option("x").filter(_ => flag).toList ::: "a" :: "b" :: "c" :: Nil
res0: List[String] = List(x, a, b, c)

scala> val flag = false
flag: Boolean = false

scala> Option("x").filter(_ => flag).toList ::: "a" :: "b" :: "c" :: Nil
res1: List[String] = List(a, b, c)
```

or conversely

```
scala> sys.props.get("flag")
res3: Option[String] = None

scala> sys.props.get("flag").map(_ => "x").toList ::: List("a","b","c")
res4: List[String] = List(a, b, c)

scala> sys.props("flag") = "true"

scala> sys.props.get("flag").map(_ => "x").toList ::: List("a","b","c")
res6: List[String] = List(x, a, b, c)
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using scalaz's ternary operator

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

val temp = List("a", "b", "c")
val list = (flag) ? ("x" :: temp) | temp


libraryDependencies += "org.scalaz" %% "scalaz-core" % "7.0.6"
```